# Python typing for a metaclass Singleton

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, metaclass

I have a Python (3.8) metaclass for a singleton as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6798042/6854595)

I've tried to add typings like so:

```py
from typing import Dict, Any, TypeVar, Type

_T = TypeVar("_T", bound="Singleton")


class Singleton(type):
    _instances: Dict[Any, _T] = {}

    def __call__(cls: Type[_T], *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> _T:
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]
```

In the line:

```
_instances: Dict[Any, _T] = {}
```

MyPy warns:

`Mypy: Type variable "utils.singleton._T" is unbound`

I've tried different iterations of this to no avail; it's very hard for me to figure out how to type this dict.

Further, the line:

```py
def __call__(cls: Type[_T], *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> _T:
```

Produces:

`Mypy: The erased type of self "Type[golf_ml.utils.singleton.Singleton]" is not a supertype of its class "golf_ml.utils.singleton.Singleton"`

How could I correctly type this?

Comment: don't do metaclass to get a singleton. 
Just create a class, and create a instance for it at a module top-level and forget about the class: there is your singleton

Comment: I know full-well that modules are only imported once and how to replicate a singleton that way. It does not fit my use case - I need to control the initialization timing explicitly, and I know what I'm doing. This is not a discussion on the singleton pattern, it's a discussion of how to type a metaclass that happens to be a singleton. I've added the singleton reference in the title because it's a continuation of a highly visited post on the topic and others may find it useful.

Comment: ok - thanks for your reply. Mine was more or less a reminder I leave on all metaclass-singleton questions (when not answering them) - so to dissuade this culture when uneeded. Obviously there are cases when it is the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing as t


_T = t.TypeVar("_T")


class Singleton(type, t.Generic[_T]):

    _instances: dict[Singleton[_T], _T] = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args: t.Any, **kwargs: t.Any) -> _T:
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]
```

Rough explanations:

1. `_T = TypeVar("_T", bound="Singleton")` is not correct - `Singleton` is `type(type(obj))` where `obj: _T = Singleton.__call__(...)`. In proper usage, the argument to `bound=` can only be `type(obj)` or some union typing construct, not `type(type(obj)`.
2. `Type variable "_T" is unbound` indicates that you need to make `Singleton` generic with respect to `_T` to bind `_T`.
3. `The erased type of self ...` error message is telling you that you've "erased" the type checker's *inferred type** of `cls`. Technically speaking, `__call__` is the same on a metaclass as any other instance method - the first argument is simply the type of the owning class. In the current static typing system, however, a metaclass's instance method's first argument is not in concordance with `type[...]`.

> *The inferred type is explicitly `Self` in the following:
>
> ```py
> import typing as t
>
> Self = t.TypeVar("Self", bound="A")
>
> class A:
>     def instancemethod(arg: Self) -> None:
>         pass
>     @classmethod
>     def classmethod_(arg: type[Self]) -> None:
>         pass
> ```

---

Runtime is important too, so the final sanity check is to make sure you've actually implemented a singleton using this metaclass:

```py
class Logger(metaclass=Singleton):
    pass

>>> print(Logger() is Logger())
True
```

Comment: This works, thanks a lot. However with the rest of your changes, it works whether "bound = Singleton" is there or not (at least mypy doesn't complain). I think I need to review the fundamentals of some of these primitives (Typevar, metaclasses and Generic)  to fully comprehend this. There's plenty in your answer to get me started, thanks.

Comment: @alexcs Type checkers' code analysis on metaclasses are very primitive (but they're a work in progress, so expect improvements). However, there's a non-metaclass-related issue that `mypy` should pick up if you run `mypy` in `--strict` mode. Try putting `bound="Singleton"` again under `--strict`, and you should get a complaint about a missing type variable.

Comment: @alexcs I've left (3) way too vague; hopefully the edits help a bit more.

Comment: I am getting `name 'Singleton' is not defined` for the field `_instances` type annotation. This `"Singleton[_T]"` seems to work though.

Comment: @Wereii Did you put `from __future__ import annotations` at the top of the module, like in the code snippet in the answer?

Comment: Is there a way to make `_instances` a `ClassVar`?
It's really an attribute of the metaclass itself and not of its instances (classes) so it makes more sense to mark `_instances` as `ClassVar`. I know `ClassVar` doesn't work well with generics, so how do we approach this?

Answer (score 0):

With the solution above, when the Singleton class is used as a metaclass the following issue in pylance:

Expected type arguments for generic class "Singleton" PylancereportMissingTypeArgument.

Looks like you have to use:
class Logger(metaclass=Singleton["Logger"]):
pass